Is un-initiated Gayatri mantra beneficial for blessings?
Does chanting the Gayatri mantra without initiation help in getting any blessings for the sadhaka?
If not where can someone get a authentic initiator for the Gayatri mantra?

Initiation into the Gayatri mantra is nothing but the upanayana ceremony. Non-brahmins are traditionally forbidden from receiving the Gayatri, for them there is the vast compendium of tantrika & shabara mantras. However, modern organisations like Gayatri Parivar & Arya Samaj initiate their followers irrespective of caste & gender into the Gayatri.

@অনু non Brahmins are traditionally forbidden - seriously? Even kshatriyas and vaishyas are allowed to receive Gayatri

So can I chant the Gayatri and benifit from it without any initiation ?
